# JHIPSTER JDL: Confusion between join field and display field

Tags: jhipster, jdl

I'm confused with the JHipster documentation [here](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/relationships#-jhipster-domain-language-jdl---relationships)

```
relationship (OneToMany | ManyToOne | OneToOne | ManyToMany) {
  <from entity>[{<relationship name>[(<display field>)]}] to <to entity>[{<relationship name>[(<display field>)]}]+
}
```

> `<display field>` is the name of the field that should show up in select
> boxes (default: id),

But in another sample the same `<display field>` is used to join, nor dispay.

```
relationship OneToOne {
  A{b(name)} to B{a(name)}
}
```

> It roughly translates to SQL: `JOIN B b with a.name = b.name`

So if I have one bi-directional relationship with two entities with "id" and I need to display the name in both... ¿The join will be done by name and not by id?

Comment: The documentation is not very clear. Maybe it means that the `<display field>` is used for both the join in SQL and the select boxes in the UI?